# On iOS App Vesion Update, will my app Users get the Updated version automatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

i am new in iOS development, i have read many post and after googling a lot didn't found any satisfactory result or answer .

recently i have developed and published an iOS app in app store. now i have update some functionality or improve some features in my iOS App, this improved version updated in App Store too and is Ready for sale in iTune Store.

now will the app user get the updates automatically, will they move from version 1.0 to 1.1 automatically or i have to do something in coding to notify the users to update???

i have a windows phone 8.1 and get the app update automatically in my phone. so according to my point of view , iOS should handle it for me...

am i right in this case or not ..???

one more thing, i am using sqlite database in my app, and it is creating by code on app first launch, after app update to new version will sqlite database affected or not...???

need some ideas or help on this issue

Comment: they will get the notification. if the users want to update the app, they will do it – but that is optional for them. you cannot assume automatically if you release the `v1.1` then every user will update it.

Comment: on update, will there be a new databse created , what would happen with prevoios database?

Comment: the `Documents` folder won't be updated at all, but your application has to be ready to update from _any_ previous version, regarding the updates are always optional, and you cannot assume every user has the recent version.

Comment: thanks for the explainations .... :)

Comment: by the way, establishing the _update policy_ has to be part of the earlier development session, and looks very unprofessional to start panicking how the updates will work _after_ you released the application for public.

Comment: :( hnnnn , you are right, but i just start working on iOS and it is released by some other colegue .

Comment: yes i checked the reaction of other users , they just downvote me :'(

Comment: probably the reason, why you have got downvotes, is summarised in my recent comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes,IOS 7 provide this feature to update app automatically.

2.Sqlite does not affect , if you want to change sqlite database table that time you copy existing table and into temporary table and delete orignal table and create it again with same name and extra columns and copy temporary table data into new created table .

Comment: 1. not only in iOS7, the update procedure is the same since iOS3 in point of view of end-users. 2. not only the _Sqlite_, the entire `Documents` folder will be untouched.

Comment: Mr. holex ,I think he mentioned only sqlite not documents.